TypeError: BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
I'm using Django to make an authentication page (login, registration...)
While I writing the login program I ran into this error and I can't understand where it come from
users/urls.py
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),

users/views.py
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'users/login.html'

    # shitty patch to bypass the error
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        # Remove 'request' from kwargs if it exists
        kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return kwargs

users/form.py
User = get_user_model()    
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    identifier = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username, Email, or Phone',
                                                             'class': 'form-control',
                                                             }))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                                 'class': 'form-control',
                                                                 'data-toggle': 'password',
                                                                 'id': 'password',
                                                                 'name': 'password',
                                                                 }))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

# this is from ChatGPT that suggested it to me to debug the problem... but it didn't clarify my ideas much
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Initialization arguments:", args, kwargs)  # Debugging line
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        identifier = self.cleaned_data.get('identifier')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if identifier and password:
            user = authenticate(username=identifier, password=password)
            if not user:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(email=identifier)
                    if not user.check_password(password):
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login credentials")
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    # Try to authenticate with phone number
                    try:
                        user = User.objects.get(phone=identifier)
                        if not user.check_password(password):
                            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login credentials")
                    except User.DoesNotExist:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login credentials")

            if user and not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This account is inactive.")

            self.cleaned_data['user'] = user
        return self.cleaned_data

    def get_user(self):
        return self.cleaned_data.get('user')

the result of ChatGPT piece of code is
Initialization arguments: () {'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/users/login/'>} and is resolved by the patch proposed.
Where/What am I doing wrong? What's the problem that elevate the error?
...last but not least... is it bad to make a login page like this, having in the same field nickname, email or phone and pass the result to the view and manipulate like so?

Instead of going to ChatGPT, isn't it easier to use Django's default User model or if you want to extend it, use CustomUser? It will save you a lot of code

First step in understanding where an error comes from is to actually read the stack trace. It will show you what is calling what. Since you've subclassed LoginView and your AuthenticationForm is receiving an unexpected keyword argument request we can guess that maybe LoginView expects the form to take an HttpRequest as the first arg. https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L286-L307 it does. So you could fix this in the __init__ method of your form, by not forwarding that kwarg to super, or as you have in the view class to not pass it to your form.

If you look at the django AuthenticationForm, the reason it takes a request is so that it can pass on the request as an arg to authenticate function. Yours probably ought to do the same (I'm not sure what is affected if you don't). So in your form __init__ method just take the request arg and store it on the form as self.request = request and then you can pass it on in the clean method.
